# Significane of using AsEnumerable() in query to take anonomous value in to view model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i just don't understand the meaning of writing AsEnumerable() in linq query.

i am having one UserDetail table in which i am fetching all details of user and i want to take
name,email in to my model.

```
 var data = context.UserDetails
                   .Select(temp => new FullName = temp.Fullname, Email = temp.Email })
                   .ToList()
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(d => new UserDetailsModel { Fullname = d.FullName, Email = d.Email })
                   .ToList();
```

What is the meaning of AsEnumerable() as because when i am removing this there is no error but as i have seen some queries where they are using this method.

And does anybody have better approach for taking anonymous object value in to my View Model?

Does it improve performance? What is the significance of this method? Can anybody explain me this method in context to my question and details?

Comment: You don't need most of this code. Your creating a collection of anonymous objects, them making it `List` then making it `IEnumerable` (which `List` already is), then converting it to `UserDetailsModel`. Just make it a collection `UserDetailsModel` in the first place

Comment: sorry didnt get you.can u please post your code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `select` is querying the database and returns `IQueryable<T>`. `.AsEnumerable()` make it `IEnumerable<T>`. `IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>` so whatever you can do with `IEnumerable<T>`, you can also do with `IQueryable<T>`.

Another big difference is that `IEnumerable<T>` fetches the entire table and applies the query on that afterwards, whereas `IQueryable<T>` only fetches the filtered data.

Note that `AsEnumerable()` does *not* materialise the query yet. You often use `.ToList()` to materialize your query so other non sql statements can be performed on the result set [as per this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645189/return-enum-name-from-integer-in-linq-database-query/26646570#26646570)

You can simplify your code to

```
var data = (from temp in context.UserDetails select temp)
  .Select(d => new UserDetailsModel
  {
    Fullname = d.fullName,
    Email = d.Email
  }).ToList());
```

Comment: but what if i am joining 2 or 3 tables and i want 2 fields from 1st table,2 field from 2nd table and 2 field from 3rd table.then can u plz show me through query that how will you achieve that by taking your example??

Comment: Just a matter or using joins in your query. [Refer this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115321/linq-to-sql-join). In this case its creating a selection of anonymous objects, but you could use `=> new UserDetailsModel` assuming `UserDetailsModel` contains all the properties you are selecting from the query

Comment: but what is the impact of asenumerable or significance??

Comment: Insignificant, but in your case its just not necessary. `IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>` so its really not doing anything useful. And the code in your question was converting `IQueryable<T>` to `List<T>` and then back to `IEnumerable<T>` which also is just adding unnecessary overhead (albeit minor unless the result set is huge)

Comment: Careful: `AsEnumarable` does *NOT* execute the query yet (execution is still deferred) while `ToList` does. So it's dangerous to use the term "materialize" as this might be misleading (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895178/331281 or https://everythingwhat.com/how-linq-query-execute)

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` work similarly, you don't need both. `List` is a `IEnumerable` + some extra features such as Add(), Count, etc., and the idea of using any of these is to materialize the query (`IQueryable`).

Also, You don't need the ***temp*** query, you could do a direct select:

```
var data = context.UserDetails
                   .Select(d => new UserDetailsModel {...})
                   .ToList()); // or AsEnumerable()
```